# Passing variable to parent window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In parent window I'm watching for changes in variable window.test

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return window.test;
}, function() {
    console.log(window.test)
});
```

On some click event I open new window and in this window i change parent's window.test value

```
window.top.opener.test = 123;
```

And when I close child window I can see, that window.test in parent has ben updated. This works just fine, but in case, that I refresh parent window before I close child one, it does not work any more. How can I handle this?

Comment: Clem if you close parent window then there will be no scope for child..

Comment: You're right of course, but I believe I never said anything about closing parent window, but about refreshing the window.

Comment: You got ans thats great thing. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found out, that if you refresh parent window after .test is changed it does not work. If you refresh before, everything works fine.

So my solution would be, to change .test just before you close child window with "download" button or something.